# Keycloak JBoss EAP7 Adapter in domain mode

Tags: jboss, keycloak

I am using Keycloak4.8.3 with JBoss EAP 7.2.2. Therefore I installed the adapter keycloak-wildfly-adapter-dist-4.8.3 on JBoss
As to the documentation I executed the command line
$ ./bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=bin/adapter-elytron-install-offline.cli

But it only modifies the standalone.xml. This is ok for my local environment.

My customer is running in domain mode and therefore the changes have to exist in domain.xml. Is there a way to automate modifying the domain.xml? I want to avoid copying the changes manually.

Answer (score 1):

First you might have to know which profile your JBoss is running with.

Then edit adapter-elytron-install-offline.cli, for every occurrence of `/subsystem`, prepend with `/profile=<your-profile-name>`

The use jboss-cli.bat along with the newly edited cli file to modify the domain mode configuration as you previously did.